# Is there a Key Difference between "Diagnosis" and "Diagnostic" Information?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction

I am trying to describe that *"**health information**"* includes other types information that is derived from diagnosis.

Is there a difference between saying:

> Health information includes ***diagnosis*** information

Or

> Health information includes ***diagnostic*** information

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Diagnostic information

is the set of information used to make a diagnosis. This is a subset of the patient's Health Information, which might include information that was not available at the time of diagnosis, or has been collected more recently.

> Diagnosis information

does not sound right to me, diagnosis is a noun. If you intend to refer to the diagnosis itself I would say something such as

> The details of the diagnosis